# ConcurrentModificationException when iterating over map

Tags: java, concurrency

I am getting `ConcurrentModificationException` when iterating over a content of a map

```
    for (String sourceKey : sMap.getContent().keySet()) {

        List<String> sourceValues = sMap.getValues(sourceKey);
        List<String> targetValues = tMap.getValues(sourceKey);

        if (areMultiple(sourceValues)) {
        ....
    }
```

`sMap.getContent()` returns `Map<String, List<String>>`, of which i am getting keys only.

Note that no modification of map's content is done. I am only iterating here.

What am i doing wrong here? How can i correct the situation when exception is thrown?

Comment: You should post the internals of your loop, as this is probably where the exception is coming from

Comment: I suggest constructing an [sscce](http://sscce.org). You will probably find something you cannot delete from your program without making the exception disappear. Look very closely at that piece of code.

Comment: Updated question to include a few more lines

Comment: @jbabey is rite. please share more details. PSR its to early to conclude, your answer should be your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will occur if the underlying collection that is being iterated over is modified by anything other than the Iterator itself.

Try using a ConcurrentHashMap instead of a plain HashMap

Comment: @Jam that is kind of disconcerting because that should not have made a difference.   `sMap.getContent().keySet()` will simply create an interator of the map's returned key set.

Comment: @PSR: There's no need to use a ConcurrentHashMap. The problem with that code is a limitation of the foreach loop, as you can read in the Java Tutorial, that says: "Use Iterator instead of the for-each construct when you need to remove the current element. The for-each construct hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove." Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html